# Why does this loop only work for one iteration?

Tags: java, arrays, debugging

I have a loop that works to remove all the zeroes in the inputted array. I used the array:

```
[[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4],[[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4]]
```

and this is the loop used to remove "all zeroes".

```
public static int[][] removeTrivialCases(int[][]array)
    int[][] correctedArray = array;

    for (int i = 0; i < correctedArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < correctedArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (correctedArray[i][j] == 0) {
                correctedArray[i] = ArrayUtils.removeElement(correctedArray[i], j);
            }
        }
    }
return correctedArray;
```

When the above array is inputted, I only get this:

```
[[0, 2, 2, 3, 4],[0, 2, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Why does this loop only remove one set of zeroes from the arrays?

**Note:** `ArrayUtils` is a class in the `ApacheLang library`.

Comment: If you're trying to *remove* elements from an *array*, you probably shouldn't be using an array. Removing elements simply isn't something that makes sense for arrays.

Comment: I have to use arrays because for the larger application of this project, simply using arrays are much more practical in terms of memory. @user2357112

Comment: Where do you initialize `correctedSums`?

Comment: and where do you add anything to `correctedArray` after you initialize it and before you return it?

Comment: Use a debugger and find out!

Comment: The problem is that you need to adjust `j` after you delete an element or it will be indexing ahead of where it should be in the new array returned by `ArrayUtils.removeElement`

Comment: Thank you it worked @MichaelPetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful when you use an integer index to go through an array, at the same time you're removing elements from the array.  Say your array is [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4].  You have a `for` loop like `for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)`.  When `i` is 0, you look up `a.get(0)`, which is 0, and then you delete the element.  This means the array is now [0, 2, 2, 3, 4].  Now the `for` loop increments `i` to 1.  What happens when you look up `a.get(1)`?  Shifting the elements in the array has caused your index to miss an element.

There are at least a couple solutions to this common problem.  One is to set up a new array to hold the results, so you're not shifting the elements in the array you're looping through.  (For large arrays, that will be more efficient anyway, since you're not shifting the same elements multiple times--you will have an O(n) algorithm instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>).)  Another is to set things up so that you increment the index only when you don't remove the element, something like

```
int i = 0;
while (i < a.length()) {
    look at a.get(i);
    ... see if you want to remove the element
    if (you want to remove the element) {
        call method to delete element from array;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now, since you increment `i` only when you don't delete the element, you will not skip any elements.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that when you increase `j` in each iteration you will skip element after removing one element because the array will shift there elements in each remove operation and you need to be sure about position of each element when removing it 
so you should adjust `j` with right index after each delete of element 
in your code `[0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 4]` when you remove element `[0][0]` from array the size of array will be `5` and first index of `j` will shifted to left `[0, 2, 2, 3, 4]` so when increase `j` you will skip the second `0` element in array

you can correct your code in this way after each removing of element decrease `j` index by one :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < correctedArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < correctedArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (correctedArray[i][j] == 0) {
                correctedArray[i] = ArrayUtils.removeElement(correctedArray[i], j);
                j--;
            }
        }
     }
```

now when you remove element you won't skip next element when you increase `j` index

I hope now the idea is clear!